# Symfony2 / Multiple Upload

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, upload

I have complete this: [SF2 Handle File Uploads with Doctrin](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html)

Now I try to do multiple upload, but can't find newer tutorial for this. All what I found is like 2+ years old, and doesn't work.

Could someone help me with this problem?

I tried change **$path**, **$file** to **array**, and add **foreach($this->file as $files)** to **upload()** function, but .... error ....

Here is my code:

**Entity:** http://pastie.org/private/1qvkhcdhojm1n1orfzuja

**Controller:** http://pastie.org/private/ppcoezaoicdufg5dsa9dw

**Twig:** http://pastie.org/private/eclba9e84kzfbh96ecgya

**PS: I need Something like this in path(in database): "image1.jpeg,image2.jpeg,image3.jpeg,..."**
Sorry, but I'm so dumb with this, just learning..

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

here is some pseudo example code showing how i access to the multiple uploaded files and persist an entity for each uploaded file

```
    $form = $this->createForm('doc',null);
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ('POST' === $request->getMethod()) {
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $data=$form->getData();

            try {
                $i=1;
                // upload each file
                foreach ($data['file'] as $item) {
                    $document = new Document();
                    $document->setFile($item);
                    // upload file 

                    $document->upload();

                    $document->setUploadedBy($user->getUserName());
                    // set thumbnail path
                    $em->persist($document);   

                    // generate images and set paths
                    $imageService->optiPathSingle($document);

                    $i++;
                }

                 return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('gleisdreieck_core_index'));

            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $form->addError(new FormError($e->getMessage()));                   
            }


        }
        return array(
            "form"=>$form->createView(),
            "tags"=>$tags
        );
    } else{
        return array(
            "form"=>$form->createView(),
            "tags"=>$tags
        );
    }
```

used formbuilder:

```
class DocumentType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder->add('file', 'file', array(
            'label' => 'Attachments',
            'required' => true,
            'attr' => array (
                'accept' => 'image/*',
                'multiple' => 'multiple'
            )
        ))
        ->add('save', 'submit');
    }
```

Comment: Thanks,

If I understand correctly, this code create few records in the database. Am I right?

Because I need 1 record in database, with path to all uploaded files. Something like this: "image1.jpeg,image2.jpeg,image3.jpeg,..."